# Single-entry visa with multiple trips in short time

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a single entry visa to visit Belgium in late October (2 nights). I applied for multiple entry through Belgium, but I only received a single entry.

I also have a ticket booked for a trip to France in mid-November (also 2 nights).

How can I obtain a visa for my France trip?

More info: I didn't know I cannot have a new visa while having unused Schengen visa, so now I have appointment to issue French visa too, for this Friday. What should be my course of action?

Comment: also related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/single-vs-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-for-spain-and-france In short, your visa allows you access to the whole Schengen area, as long as you don't leave it. If the only border you cross is France/belgium no problem.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the countries you are visiting are part of the Schengen treaty, you should be fine, you will only need a multiple entry visa if you will be going into a Schengen country then to another country which is not a member, an then in  again.

In your case both Belgium and France are members of this treaty, so again, you won't need a multi-entry visa.

If you need to be more confident about this, you could consult with the French Embassy in your country of residence.