# What is a single-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, terminology

I am travelling to Paris and Italy for tourist purpose. My itinerary will be
Mumbai -> Paris -> Italy -> Paris -> Mumbai.

So my question is if I have single Entry Visa, would be Ok to enter in Paris again?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/single-vs-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-for-spain-and-france?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: on Some posts its written as you can Entry any schengen country once... But in my travel I am entering Paris twice...

Comment: Think of it this way:  For the purpose of the short term visa Schengen area is one big country so your only concern is an external border.  The posts here mention entry and exit to "Schengen Area" not any single Schengen State.

Comment: Okie... That means... I will be entering in schengen area, Paris first, then I will be travelling to Italy which is also schengen area... And I will be returning to Paris (schengen area) again.. That will be fine.

Comment: Which is exactly what 2 other questions linked are stating.

Comment: Yes, I agree those are same as what I am asking.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will be OK (provided everything else is in order). For this purpose, you can look at the the whole Schengen area as a single country. You can only enter *from a non-Schengen country* once but you can leave and enter a particular Schengen country as many times as you want as long as you are not leaving the area.

There can always be some random passport check (it seems somewhat common when coming from Italy) but you won't get an entry or exit stamp when traveling between France, Italy and Switzerland. In fact, there probably won't be a police check at all, even if you are flying.

Comment: So you mean to say your allowed to have enter and exit as many as you can from schengen area.. e.g. I can go to Germany and from Germany i can go to Italy and again I can come back to Germany as many as I can ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Okie... Great!
I will be traveling to Paris -> Italy -> Paris with Single Entry Visa...so that should be fine :)