# Schengen visa to France and Sweden

Tags: visas, schengen, france, sweden, vietnamese-citizens

I'm a non-EU student in the UK for almost a year. I plan to apply for Schengen visa to France- Sweden this August. This is my first time applying for the visa so I have some concerns if you could help me, it's much appreciated.

1. Should I apply for a single or multi-entry visa?
2. If I apply for a multi-entry visa, after my UK-France-Sweden-UK trip, will I be able to use the current visa to later go to other Schengen countries (maybe in September) or I can re-visit only France and Sweden?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What citizenship do you hold? Answer to your first question is here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/single-vs-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-for-spain-and-france?rq=1

Comment: I'm Vietnamese. Thank you Karlson for the answer to my first question. I'm still confused between single and multi-entry regarding the second question, if you could help?

Answer (score 2):

As you indicated your first port of entry is France, you should apply for a Schengen visa with the French consulate.  Incidentally, they are the best at granting longer-term multi-entry visa.

It's been a while since I needed to do this, but at the time, there was no difference in price between a single- and multi-entry visa.  What you should do is state in the application form your intended itinerary as entering France, staying in France, then on to Sweden, then back to UK - **and then later travelling to France again**.  You can also submit a cover letter explaining in more details why you are requesting a multi-entry visa.

It is quite common for French consulate in the UK to issue multi-entry visa valid for 6 months to first-time applicants.  Many other countries would automatically issue a single-entry visa for you.

Once you complete your first trip, as long as the visa is still valid (date-wise), you are allowed to visit any other Schengen country, provided you return to the UK by the expiry date on the visa.