# Single entry schengen visa for a cruise?

Tags: visas, schengen, cruising

If I am taking a cruise starting from Rome and covering only Schengen countries. Is single entry Schengen visa adequate for the trip

Comment: What passport do you have?

Comment: @MarkMayo The nationality could at most question its premises (namely that a visa is required at all) but cannot possibly change the answer to the question.

Comment: @Relaxed I don't know enough about schengen, if I see a visa/passport question without a citizenship, I just tend to ask *in case* it helps :)

Comment: What does the cruise line itself say you need?

Answer (score 4):

As long as you stay within the Schengen area, you only need a single entry visa.

**EDIT**

References

1. http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/
2. [Single vs. Multiple entry Schengen visa, for Spain and France?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/single-vs-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-for-spain-and-france?rq=1)

Comment: This statement needs a little clarification. On your cruise you'll be traveling with a vessel. If the vessel route includes calls at non-Schengen ports, all its movements are treated as international. All passengers will undergo passport control at all Schengen ports. Thus, a multiple-entry visa will be needed. This applies to all passengers, even those who only do the 'intra-Schengen' part of the voyage. For example, if you're taking a vessel whose full route includes a stop in Turkey, you will be passport-controlled in all ports even if you only travel from Spain to Italy.

Comment: Your point is valid @AndreyChernyakhovskiy. But the question is pertaining to only the Schengen countries that the cruise is covering. So based on that I gave the answer above.